# Best approach to having consistent datetime formats between SQL Server & VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

I am developing a VB.Net application that has operations which rely heavily on dates & times. As there could be conflicts on date formats if the application date format doesn't match the server date format what is the best practice to resolve this issue. I know that SQL Server `datetime` format depend on the server language & VB.Net will use the local machine datetime format. Which means if a user changes the datetime format it will cause problems when inserting.

My idea is to use `SELECT GETDATE()` on application startup, then identify its datetime format using VB.Net & whenever I try to insert a datetime value I will convert it to the datetime format identified at the application startup.

Is there a better approach to having a consistent datetime formats between the application & SQL Server to avoid comflicts. eg: Mixing a day with a month.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

So if ever possible, **don't convert** dates between `DateTime` and string all the time! Leave it as `DateTime` in .NET, use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` in SQL Server, and let the dates be in their native format. Use **parametrized queries** that support the native `DateTime` datatype so you **don't need** to convert dates to string and back!

If you must use strings to represent dates for whatever reason, the only reliable way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Comment: Using parametrized queries did the trick, now the database will automatically handle it no matter which ever format I pass into it thanks.

Comment: very nice and complete answer +1