# SQL Sever: create string date from current year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server stored procedure I am trying to check if current date is between two dates of the current year:

```
IF @MyDate BETWEEN '03/02/2017' AND '10/05/2017 23:59'
BEGIN
  // Do some stuff
END
```

@MyDate is a datetime variable which is passed by parameter to my stored procedure.

But I need to program it in order to work for succesive years. Now is only working for year 2017 and I need it to work with 2018, 2019 and so on.

For example, for 2018 it will be:

```
IF @MyDate BETWEEN '03/02/2018' AND '10/05/2018 23:59'
BEGIN
  // Do some stuff
END
```

for 2019 it will be:

```
IF @MyDate BETWEEN '03/02/2019' AND '10/05/2019 23:59'
BEGIN
  // Do some stuff
END
```

and so on. The date range is always the same, only year is changing so I need it to adjust automatically.

So how to modify my conditional IF to adapt it?

Comment: Use functions `DATEPART` to extract the day and month and then remake the date using the `GETDATE` function with `YEAR` for the current year

Comment: What is a _strind date_?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = '12-11-2017'
DECLARE @currYear INT = 2017

--Put this part inside a loop or function may be

DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @currYear)
DECLARE @fromDate DATETIME = '03/02/'+@year 
DECLARE @toDate DATETIME = '10/05/'+@year+' 23:59'

IF @MyDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
BEGIN
  PRINT '1'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
  PRINT '2'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new date as follows

```
CAST(CAST(y AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(m AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(d AS varchar) AS DATETIME)
```

where `y` is `YEAR(GETDATE)` for the current year and `m` and `d` are the month and day which can be generated from `DATEPART`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) for use of `DATEPART`

IN SQL Server 2012 onwards there is the function `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` or `DATEFROMPARTS`

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) to return a consistent year.  In this example I've picked 0001 (the year 0000 would be easier to work with, but it isn't a valid SQL Server date).

```
-- All years are set to 0001.
IF DATEADD(YEAR, -(YEAR(@MyDate) -1), @MyDate) BETWEEN '00010203' AND '00010510'
BEGIN

    -- Do stuff...
END
```

Here's a breakdown of how we're using DateAdd:

```
DATEADD
(
    YEAR,                   -- Tell dateadd we are working with years.
    -                       -- We are going to subtract not add.
    (YEAR(@MyDate) -1),     -- Number of years to remove from @MyDate, to get to 0001. 
    @MyDate                 -- Your date.
)
```

SQL Server 2012, and above, includes the [DateFromParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) function.  The basic approach is the same but, in my opinion, you end up with a cleaner statement.

```
IF DATEFROMPARTS(1, MONTH(@MyDate), DAY(@MyDate)) BETWEEN '00010203' AND '00010510'
```

You don't need to include the time stamp.  [Between](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql) is inclusive of the entire start and end day.  Unless I misunderstood and you meant to exclude the final minute of May 10th.

Slightly off-topic but worth a read: [SQL Server Date Formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115781/best-approach-to-having-consistent-datetime-formats-between-sql-server-vb-net).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a date of current year by using `DATEADD`

```
DATEADD(year, datediff(year, '20160302', getdate()), '20160302')
```

So your condition could be

```
IF @MyDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year, datediff(year, '20160302', getdate()), '20160302') 
           AND DATEADD(year, datediff(year, '20160510 23:59:59', getdate()), '20160510 23:59:59')
```